# flask ndb.model auto created_by field

Tags: flask, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have an ndb.Model

```
class BaseModel(ndb.Model):
    created_on = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='MyUser') # ????
```

I'm looking for an elegant way create an auto "created_by" field that is populated with g.current_user key upon creation, so that

```
mymodel = BaseModel()
```

already have created_on and created_by

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend defining your own property class:

```
class OwnerProperty(ndb.KeyProperty):

  _auto_current_user_add = False

  def __init__(self, auto_current_user_add=False):
    super(OwnerProperty, self).__init__(kind='MyUser')
    self._auto_current_user_add = auto_current_user_add

  def _prepare_for_put(self, entity):
    if self._auto_current_user_add and not self._has_value(entity):
      value = g.current_user.key
      if value is not None:
        self._store_value(entity, value)
    super(OwnerProperty, self)._prepare_for_put(entity)
```

I'm not really sure how your `g.current_user` is setup, but assuming it is an Entity this would work. Note that like `ndb.DateTimeProperty`, the owner would only get populated once the entity is put for the first time.

This is based on how [`ndb.UserProperty` is written](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/model.py#1833). However, I recommend against using `UserProperty` directly since user properties do a lot of strange things so it is always better to handle your own user entities.

Answer (score 0):

ended up doing something simple:

```
class BaseModel(ndb.Model):
    created_on = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='TalknetUser')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseModel, self).__init__(parent=talknet_key(), *args, **kwargs)
        try:
            self.created_by = current_user.ndb.key
        except Exception as x:
            self.created_by = None
```

but so far it works